# PHP - Parse big XML URL

Tags: php, xml

I got a problem to parse an xml URL. This xml is big, I wait in 2 minutes to load this xml URL. So when I parse it with the XMLReader or simpleXML_load_file, that reach the limit to excute. Everything is fine if I store the XML file in local, I can read it easily.

So any suggestion ? I read all the similar situation in stackoverflow but this case is diffrent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one or more of

- increase the timeouts and possibly size restrictions on your local server or php instance
- find a way to only download the new part of the xml and use that to update a local file containing the remainder of the data
- download the entire file occasionally and use the cached copy